# iPod Classic 160GB just will not start any help appreciated

Tags: itunes, ipod-classic

My 160gb iPod Classic will not turn on or do anything It does not get recognised by iTunes when I hold the Menu and Centre button the apple logo appears but does not start, if I hold the same buttons for longer a red circle with a cross inside it appears.  Any ideas how I can get my iPod started or do you think it might need a visit to apple support shop.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be short, please check this support page from Apple to troubleshoot your problem:
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203170

If that doesn't work your last shot is at a service point.